# Constructors with named arguments setting private variables post validations

Tags: flutter, dart

For a StatelessWidget, how can I have a constructor with named arguments and set private final variables after doing certain validations.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  const MyWidget({bool foo}) : /*do validation e.g. ArgumentError.checkNotNull(foo)*/ _foo = foo;

  final bool _foo;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  MyWidget({bool foo})
      : assert(foo != null), // validation
        _foo = foo; // assigning value

  final bool _foo;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```